# Open calendar from past day on android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open calendar from past days.For example today's date is 25-Nov-2016.Calendar should open from 24-Nov-2016 to 1-01-1900 and user can select any past date.These is my snippet code

`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
fromYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
fromMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
fromDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

Note:Calendar should not show current day and future days.

Comment: set mindate and maxdate.

Comment: As simple you need to set minimum and maximum date !

Answer (score 0):

`DatePickerDialog` has methods `setMaxDate(Long millis)` and `setMinDate(Long millis)`

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Min and MAx Date as per you want

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
//dp_time.setMinDate(now);
dp_time.setMaxDate(now-(1000*60*60*24*1));
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year    = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month   = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day     = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), listener, year, month, day);
    Field mDatePickerField;
    try {
            mDatePickerField = dialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDatePicker");
            mDatePickerField.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    return dialog;
}
```